# Not unique table/alias: 'dig'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull data from 5 tables and display the data.

```
ple_active_starter
ple_parkeon_starter
ple_pbp_starter 
ple_ips_starter 
ple_dig_starter
```

```
SELECT
    ac.route,
    ac.address,
    ac.time_restriction_summary,
    ac.paybyphone_number,
    dig.total_coll, 
    ips.amount,
    par.amount, 
    pbp.total ,
    pbp.status,
    ac.old_meter_number,
    par.payment_type
FROM ple_active_starter ac, ple_parkeon_starter par, ple_pbp_starter pbp, ple_ips_starter ips, ple_dig_starter dig
INNER JOIN dig ON dig.process_date = ips.transaction_date
```

I continue to get the error message "Not unique table/alias :dig".

What am I doing wrong? Any information you can share on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider formatting your post, it's not human readable at all.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, ... Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `JOIN` statement

```
INNER JOIN dig ON dig.process_date = ips.transaction_date
```

to below

```
INNER JOIN ple_dig_starter dig ON dig.process_date = ips.transaction_date
```

Change your query `FROM` part to be below

```
FROM ple_active_starter ac
INNER JOIN dig ON dig.process_date = ac.some_column;
```

Comment: @user2974907, your query JOINS are total weird. See edit in answer and try making changes accordingly.